# create-react-app not create a project

Tags: react.js

the create-react-app install all dependencies (node_modules folder), create the  package.json and yarn.lock files, but not create the app structure.
the cdm stop like in the image [cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZ1dz.png).
what's the problem with it?

- node version: 10.16.0
- npm version: 6.9.0
- yarn version: 1.17.3
- OS: windows 8.1

Answer (score 0):

The basic command to create a react app is:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Check out the documentation for the whole setup in [this link](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html).